# Export non-varchar data to CSV table using Trino (formerly PrestoDB)

Tags: csv, hive, presto, trino

I am working on some benchmarks and need to compare ORC, Parquet and CSV formats. I have exported TPC/H (SF1000) to ORC based tables. When I want to export it to Parquet I can run:

```
CREATE TABLE hive.tpch_sf1_parquet.region
  WITH (format = 'parquet')
  AS SELECT * FROM hive.tpch_sf1_orc.region
```

When I try the similar approach with CSV, then I get the error `Hive CSV storage format only supports VARCHAR (unbounded)`. I would assumed that it would convert the other datatypes (i.e. `bigint`) to text and store the column format in the Hive metadata.

I can export the data to CSV using `trino --server trino:8080 --catalog hive --schema tpch_sf1_orc --output-format=CSV --execute 'SELECT * FROM nation`, but then it gets emitted to a file. Although this works for SF1 it quickly becomes unusable for SF1000 scale-factor. Another disadvantage is that my Hive metastores wouldn't have the appropriate meta-data (although I could patch it manually if nothing else works).

Anyone an idea how to convert my ORC/Parquet data to CSV using Hive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Trino Hive connector, the CSV table can contain `varchar` columns only.

You need to cast the exported columns to `varchar` when creating the table

```
CREATE TABLE region_csv
WITH (format='CSV')
AS SELECT CAST(regionkey AS varchar), CAST(name AS varchar), CAST(comment AS varchar)
FROM region_orc
```

Note that you will need to update your benchmark queries accordingly, e.g. by applying reverse casts.

Comment: There is no way to get around the Hive limitation of unbounded varchar, so your answer is the only correct answer. There is an option to generate CSV-ish files, but it's dangerous. For completeness, I have added this "answer" too.

Comment: You're correct. People will often use `TEXTFILE` table format to process CSV data.

Answer (score 2):

**DISCLAIMER:** Read the full post, before using anything discussed here. It's not real CSV and you migth screw up!

It is possible to create typed CSV-ish tables when using the TEXTFILE format and use ',' as the field separator:

```
CREATE TABLE hive.test.region (
  regionkey bigint,
  name varchar(25),
  comment varchar(152)
)
WITH (
  format = 'TEXTFILE',
  textfile_field_separator = ','
);
```

This will create a typed version of the table in the Hive catalog using the `TEXTFILE` format. It normally uses the ^A character (ASCII 10), but when set to ',' it resembles the same structure as CSV formats.

**IMPORTANT**: Although it looks like CSV, it is not real CSV. It doesn't follow [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), because it doesn't properly quote and escape. The following INSERT will not be inserted co:

```
INSERT INTO hive.test.region VALUES (
  1,
  'A "quote", with comma',
  'The comment contains a newline
in it');
```

The text will be copied unmodified to the file without escaping quotes or commas. This should have been written like this to be proper CSV:

```
1,"A ""quote"", with comma","The comment contains a newline
in it"
```

Unfortunately, it is written as:

```
1,A "quote", with comma,The comment contains a newline
in it
```

This results in invalid data that will be represented by NULL columns. For this reason, this method can only be used when you have full control over the text-based data and are sure that it doesn't contain newlines, quotes, commas, ...

Comment: whats the solution of it. by using TEXTFILE format how we can double quotes values in fields ?